# Fragment sendo usado por duas activties diferentes

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho um fragment que está inflando uma recycler view, até ai tudo bem. O problema é que esse fragment precisa inflar em dois navigation drawer diferentes, e na hora de fazer a cast, só consigo fazer a cast para um deles.

Tem alguma maneira de na hora de fazer a cast, ele identificar qual a classe que está chamando o fragment, e fazer a cast daquela determinada classe?

Segue abaixo o código que está dando erro.

```
comunicadosList = ((NvdResp) getActivity()).getSetComunicadosList(3);
    ComunicadosAdapter adapter = new ComunicadosAdapter(getActivity(), comunicadosList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

além da classe NvdResp(Que onde faço a cast para buscar na minha list os itens a serem inflados) também tenho a classe NvdAluno. Eu poderia criar uma classe genérica ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Acho que usar esse esquema de casting para o que você está fazendo não é o ideal. Acho que devia fazer usando interface. A propósito, também acho estranho usar Fragments em uma RecyclerView. Não sabe uma custom view aí?

Comment: Na verdade o Fragment está inflando a RecyclerView dentro do NavigationDrawer. o problema é que minha aplicação trabalha com dois perfis aluno e responsável, e justamente esse Fragment precisa ser inflado nos dois NavigationDrawer, só que se eu colocar em um NavigationDrawer(no caso do exemplo o NvdResp) o outro NavigationDrawer(no caso o NvdAluno) da erro na cast, estava pensando em criar uma nova classe e colocar minha List nela e fazer a cast para essa classe, depois instanciar a classe dentro dos meus NavigationDrawer.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com CustomView, vou dar uma procurada, sabe né conhecimento nunca é demais ; - )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando um *Fragment* necessita de aceder a métodos da *Activity*, ele deve forçar a *Activity* a implementar uma interface que defina esses métodos.

Assim, o *cast* pode ser feito para a *interface* e não para uma implementação de uma *Activity* em particular.

Comece por declarar a *interface*:

```
public interface ComunicadosListProvider {
      public ComunicadosList getSetComunicadosList(int valor);

      //Nota: substitua ComunicadosList pelo tipo da sua lista
}
```

e um campo para guardar um objecto que a implemente:

```
ComunicadosListProvider mComunicadosListProvider;
```

No `onAttach()` do *Fragment* guarde nele uma referência à *interface*, a *Activity* tem de implementar essa interface.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {                           //cast feito para a interface
        mComunicadosListProvider = (ComunicadosListProvider) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
        + " deve implementar ComunicadosListProvider");
    }
}
```

Quando quiser chamar o método use:

```
comunicadosList = mComunicadosListProvider.getSetComunicadosList(3);
ComunicadosAdapter adapter = new ComunicadosAdapter(getActivity(), comunicadosList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Não tinha a minima ideia de como fazer isso !!!